# Old wireless adapter - MT7630E, Asus laptop - used to work in 20.04, doesn't anymore

Tags: networking, drivers

I was able to find a driver at https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E and somehow made it work, but then it stopped - probably after an update. Would love some advice on how to get it going again.

Ran a script to capture adapter info -just not sure what to try next. Output is at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9C545tghjJ/.

Appreciate ideas.

Comment: If this was something you had to custom compile, you’ll need to recompile after every kernel update.

Comment: Seems like the right way to go. Can you point me to a "how-to" on that? It can't be too hard, because I obviously did it once before - just not sure what to try next. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you `sudo modprobe -v mt76x0e`

Comment: After reboot, the adapter loads. If that's all I have to do after updates, it's a small price to pay. Thanks for the clue.

I did try to download and compile a custom kernel. It wasn't fun, and it didn't work.